# im trying to make a "user taken" validation in this php code and it gives me this error:

Tags: php, validation

this is the code that i used:

```
<?php
$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');
if (!empty($username)){
if (!empty($password)){
$host = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "1234";
$dbname = "admin";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli ($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);


$dbunames = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM entity WHERE username='$username'");



if (mysqli_num_rows($dbunames) > 0 ) { //check if there is already an entry 
for that username
    echo "Already taken";
  }



 else{
 $sql = "INSERT INTO entity (username, password)
 values ('$username','$password')";
 if ($conn->query($sql)){
  echo "New record is inserted sucessfully";
 }
 else{
  echo "Error: ". $sql ."
 ". $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
}
}
else{
 echo "Password should not be empty";
die();
}
}
 else{
 echo "Username should not be empty";
 die();
 }


 ?>
```

and this is the error(in the web):

```
 Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in 
 C:\xampp\htdocs\form\connect.php on line 15

 Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null 
 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\form\connect.php on line 19
 New record is inserted sucessfully
```

i know "the record is inserted sucessfully" but the username is already taken validation is not working.
i'm not good at php so i would be pleased if you tell me how to fix this code simply.

please help me!!!

Comment: change your` mysqli_query` to this line: `$dbunames = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM entity WHERE username='$username'");` You missing the `$conn` in the mysqli_query which needs two parameters to be passed.

Comment: The error messages tell you everything you need to know. `mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given` Also not to familiar with the `filter_input` but from the manual sounds like that does nothing for you with your current settings. `This will result in no filtering taking place by default.` Parameterize your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add $conn variable at the `// Create connection` section so it should be:

```
$dbunames = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM entity WHERE username='$username'");
```

Also **Always store your passwords as Hash!!**

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I have to do that (they were plain text).

Answer (score 1):

```
$dbunames = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM entity WHERE username='$username'");
```

needs to use the $conn variable like so:

```
$dbunames = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM entity WHERE username='$username'");
```

Comment: @user3783243 so how could i prevent sql injection's(in this code)?

Comment: @Daniel Parameterize the query, as the below answer demonstrates. Never put user data into a query, and preferable just never put values into a query. If values need to go in put them in a placeholder and bind them. There are a few threads already about this topic, that's the simplest I can explain it in.

Comment: @user3783243 I dont down vote. its mean.  I dont want to be mean

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the $conn as the first parameter in your query.  Because your query is not being executed correctly the `mysql_num_rows()` is not working either.

Change

```
 $dbunames = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM entity WHERE username='$username'");
```

To

```
$dbunames = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM entity WHERE username='$username'");
```

Additionally, your query as it is written now is not safe against sql injection.  You should take 30 mins to read up on how to use parameterized queries.  It's not bad at all, learn it now so you can make sure all your queries going forward are coded correctly.  It's just the right thing to do.
Here is a good link to read that will explain parameterized queries using mysqli.  [Good SQL Practices](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Here is an example of how to properly code your query that you have above.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM entity WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if($result->num_rows > 0){

echo "That username is already taken.";

}

$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

As i said in my comment:
`mysqli_query` function needs two parameters to be passed.

Change this:

```
$dbunames = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM entity WHERE username='$username'");
```

to this one:

```
$dbunames = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM entity WHERE username='$username'");
```